# How to use velocity while swiping through a list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

So at the moment I am deciding which way to snap by checking position of the endTouch (either left or right of the screen) then hard code the animation with the Duration of 150milliseconds.

I am trying to use the scroll velocity deciding where to snap when the user let go.(the Idea is user shouldn't slide all the way to the middle to slide to the next or previous card).

[image]

this is my `AnimationController`

```
finishScrollAnimation = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 150),
      vsync: this,
    )
    ..addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        scrollPercent = lerpDouble(finishScrollStart, finishScrollEnd, finishScrollAnimation.value);
      });
    })
    ;
```

this is the `_onHorizontalDragEnd` method

```
 void _onHorizontalDragEnd(DragEndDetails details) {
    final unitsPerSecondX = details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx / context.size.width;
    final unitsPerSecond = Offset(unitsPerSecondX, 0.0);
    final unitVelocity = unitsPerSecond.distance;
    print(unitVelocity);

    final numCards = 3;
    finishScrollStart = scrollPercent;  // this is the endTouch
    finishScrollEnd = (scrollPercent * numCards).round() / numCards;  // this just calculating where to snap
    finishScrollAnimation.forward(from: 0.0);

    setState(() {
      startDrag = null;
      startDragScrollPercent = null;
    });
  }
```

this is roughly all the code needed to recreate [My current output](https://dartpad.dev/f414d8342b2d21eb3fd11ef35b66909b?).

I can't wrap logic around it, so any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? The question seems incomplete. Please state the problem faced by you clearly and how the current output differs from the desired one.

Comment: I added some more details hopefully its more clear, if any thing else is not clear kindly let me know @AfridiKayal

Comment: why don't just use horizontal ListView with `physics: PageScrollPhysics(),` ?

Comment: I am going to perfom some opacity fade while swiping I thought it would be easier for me to control those Items individualy when using `Stack` @someuser

Comment: it wouldn't be easier, you can add listener to controller and change opacity during page transition

Comment: Ok, let me try that and see if it helps me better @someuser will get back